# Did the author of Alice in Wonderland make any substantial original discoveries in mathematics?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians

Charles Lutwidge Dodgson, better known by his pen name of Lewis Carroll, was a mathematics lecturer at Oxford University and today is primarily famous for his fanciful stories laced with mathematical and logical jokes. He also seems to have been a somewhat prolific writer of math *textbooks* in his day, but it's not clear whether he made any significant original *discoveries* in math.

Did he?

Comment: The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_Carroll#Mathematical_work) article mentions the he is credited with the first printed proof of the [Kronecker-Capelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem).  He is also credited with inventing the [Dodgson condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodgson_condensation) algorithm for computing determinants.  It also mentions a number of other contributions, but without giving details.

Comment: Hi, interesting question, but did you consider first looking him up either in Wikipedia or in any of the many online short biographies?  Sometimes that helps you better focus your question (or answer it!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used C. L. DODGSQN, Condensation of determinants. Proc. Royal Sot. London 15 (1866). 150-155 in one of my papers. But for some reason I cited a secondary reference instead, D. P. Robbins and H. Rumsey, Jr., Determinants and alternatig sign matrices, Adv. Math. 62 (1986), 169-184.